# Paint instance never initializated in custom ViewGroup constructor

Tags: android

I have a custom ViewGroup with the follow constructors:

```
public BoxGridLayout(Context context) {
    super(context, null);
}

public BoxGridLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs, 0);
}

public BoxGridLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    //Recupero gli attributi che ho creato nel file attrs.xml
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.BoxGridLayout, 0, defStyle);

    int strokeWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.BoxGridLayout_separatorWidth, 0);
    int strokeColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.BoxGridLayout_separatorColor, Color.WHITE);

    a.recycle();

    mGridPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mGridPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mGridPaint.setColor(strokeColor);
    mGridPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
}
```

After that in the dispatchDraw() method, I need mGridPaint to create a grid:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

    for (int i = 0; i <= getWidth(); i += (getWidth() / COUNT)) {
        canvas.drawLine(i, 0, i, getHeight(), mGridPaint);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= getHeight(); i += (getHeight() / COUNT)) {
        canvas.drawLine(0, i, getWidth(), i, mGridPaint);
    }
}
```

I used this ViewGroup in a layout file like the following:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<com.example.customview.widget.BoxGridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:separatorWidth="2dp">

   ....
   ....


</com.example.customview.widget.BoxGridLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

**Problem:** Sadly I have a NullPointerException on mGridPaint:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'long android.graphics.Paint.mNativePaint' on a null object reference
        at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawLines(GLES20Canvas.java:862)
        at android.view.GLES20Canvas.drawLine(GLES20Canvas.java:852)
        at it.liqid.customview.widgets.BoxGridLayout.dispatchDraw(BoxGridLayout.java:94)
        .....
```

How can I fix this error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor invoked by the layout inflater is `public BoxGridLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)`. Change

```
public BoxGridLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs, 0);
}
```

with

```
public BoxGridLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}
```

or initialize the painter also in the constructor with two parameters

But be aware that the constructor with `int defStyle` is available since API Level 11. You can also have a `public void init()` method where you provide  the   initialization  common to the three constructors

Comment: yep sorry.. I should have explained  the difference.. In the former you are calling directly the super constructor, in the latter you call the overridden constructor which, in turn, calls the super constructor